# NSNotification not being called when UIButton triggered

Tags: uibutton, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I don't understand why a `NSNotification` I'm trying to send  is not being called when I pulse a `UIButton`. I'm trying to send an object from a `ViewController` to other `ViewController` with `Notifications`.

My code:

In **Viewcontroller.m** :

```
 - In Init method:
[self.goPanelRightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMovePanelRight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (IBAction)btnMovePanelRight:(id)sender

{
    UIButton *button = sender;

    switch (button.tag) {
        case 0: {

            [self movePanelToOriginalPosition];
            break;
        }

        case 1: {

            [self sendModel];
            NSLog(@"Entered case 1");
            [self movePanelRight];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)sendModel{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kModelNotification
                                                        object:self
                                                    userInfo:@{GALLERY_KEY:self.model}];
```

In **ObserverViewController**:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(getModelMain:)
                   name:kModelNotification
                 object:nil];

}

    }


-(void)getModelMain:(NSNotification *) notification{
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];

    self.model=[dict objectForKey:GALLERY_KEY];
}
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with Key Value Coding. Passing the object before I change to the next view:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"setModel:");

if ([self.leftPanelViewController respondsToSelector:selector]) {

   [self.leftPanelViewController setValue:self.model forKey:@"model"];

}
```